# Browser doesn't prompt to download file - Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, csv, axios

[SOLVED] Had to split the download() method in 2, so it goes as generateCSV() and then getDownload().

After the the generation of the file, added this on sweetalert confirm button, which route points to getDownload().

```
preConfirm: () => {
    window.location.href = "/customers/resale/filterToCSV/download";
}
```

After the user selects a few checkboxes for filtering a database table, the server writes to a CSV file, but it doesn't prompt the browser to download it.

**route:**

```
Route::get('/customers/resale/filterToCSV', 'Resale_customerController@getFilteredQueryResults');
```

**blade view:**

```
axios.get('/customers/resale/filterToCSV', {
    params: {
        dataFromClient: arrJson,
    }
})
.then(function (response) {
    Swal.fire({
        icon: 'success',
        title: '...',
        text: '...',
    })
    console.log("Response (Filtered data to CSV): " + response.data);
});
```

**controller:**

```
public function getFilteredQueryResults(Request $request)
{
    $arr = json_decode($request->dataFromClient, true);

    $selection = $this->queryBuilderFromCheckboxSelection($arr);
    $jsn = $selection->toJson();

    $this->download($jsn);

}
```

which calls the `download()` method:

```
public function download($jsn)
{
    $filePath = public_path().'\\file.csv';

    $headers = array(
        "Content-type" => "text/csv",
        "Content-Disposition" => "attachment; filename=file.csv",
        "Pragma" => "no-cache",
        "Cache-Control" => "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0",
        "Expires" => "0"
    );

    $jsonDecoded = json_decode($jsn, true);

    $csvFileName = 'file.csv';

    $fp = fopen($csvFileName, 'w');

    foreach ($jsonDecoded as $row) {
        fputcsv($fp, $row);
    }

    fclose($fp);

    echo response()->download($filePath, $csvFileName, $headers);
    return response()->download($filePath, $csvFileName, $headers);//->deleteFileAfterSend(true);

}
```

Any idea what am I missing? Thank you!

Comment: You're trying with this `echo` commented out, right? Also, you forgot to `return` in controller. It should be `return $this->download($jsn);`

Comment: yes, but it still doesn't download :(

Comment: Update your question with the actual code, please.